# Asking for user input for a 2d array and storing the data in the array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a code to help Santa track the number of presents he needs for a street, and I am trying to do it through the use for a 2D array, and nested for loops, and apparently this is the right way of doing it, but the program tends to crash after asking for the number of kids in the second house. the code is shown below:

```
void distribute_presents()
{
   int houses, kids=0;
   int KidsInStreet[houses][kids];
   int i, j;
   printf("Enter the number of houses in the street?\n");
   scanf("%d", &houses);
   printf("Enter the number of kids in the street?\n");
   scanf("%d", &kids);
   for (i=0;i<=houses;i++)
   {
       for (j=0;j<=kids;j++)
       {
           printf("Enter the number of kids in house %d:\n", i+1, j+1);
           scanf("%d", KidsInStreet[i][j]);
       }
    }
     printf("The presents and their respective prices are:\n");
     for(i=0;i<=houses;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<=kids;j++)
    {
        printf("%d", KidsInStreet[i][j]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You've initialized kids to 0, and left houses uninitialized.  You then use those two variables as the size of the array.  Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: But I thought adding the comma meant that both are intialised

Comment: There is a mismatch in the number of arguments here: `printf("Enter the number of kids in house %d:\n", i+1, j+1);`

Comment: How do you mean

Answer (score 3):

I think you should query for the number of houses and kids *first*, then populate the 2D array:

```
void distribute_presents()
{
    int houses, kids = 0;
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter the number of houses in the street?\n");
    scanf("%d", &houses);
    printf("Enter the number of kids in the street?\n");
    scanf("%d", &kids);
    int KidsInStreet[houses][kids];

    for (i=0; i < houses; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < kids; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the number of kids in house %d:\n", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &KidsInStreet[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The presents and their respective prices are:\n");
    for (i=0; i < houses; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < kids; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", &KidsInStreet[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but why does that make difference though, surely it shouldn't matter? thanks

Comment: @BarryBBenson In your current code, you defined the 2D array to be zero by zero.  Once you have made this definition, it cannot be altered.  Simply changing the values of the `houses` and `kids` variables does not change the dimensions of the 2D array.

Comment: i tried and it didn't make a difference, as the code breaks at the same place

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but the code still breaks

Comment: Check my updated answer, in particular the two loops at the end.  Use `&KidsInStreeet` as the input into `scanf`.  And note that I changed the bounds of the loop.  Arrays span from zero to one minus the length of the array; they don't start at one.

Comment: Thanks that has worked, but there is a bug, that when i enter the number of houses on the street and the kids, the program, is suppossed to ask to enter the kids in house 1, 2, 3..., but what it does is that it says to enter the number of kids in house 1, and loops it for the number of houses in the street and does the same thing for 2, until the number of houses is equal to the number of kids, thanks for teh fix though

Comment: @BarryBBenson Your logic does not make much sense actually.  One dimension of the array is number houses, but it doesn't make much sense for the other dimension to be number of children.  Maybe explain more about the original problem and we can update the code.

Comment: Just for completeness: Your answer implies the availability of Variable Length Arrays. VLAs were introduced with C99 only, an are optional since C11. Also certain vendors do not follow the C Standard.

Comment: Your 2D array implies that every child _in_ every house has some integer property that you want to record.  Off the top of my head, maybe it's number of days attending school, amount of money, etc.

Comment: Ok, this was the instruction I was given:

Comment: Santa wants store data in a 2D array, KidsInStreet, to track how many children live at each house in a street
 E.g. for each street he visits he needs to know how many presents to leave at each house

Comment: @BarryBBenson I would possibly model that (in a simplified way) as a 2D array where the first dimension is the street and the second the house on that street.  Stored in each point in the 2D array would be the number of children.  But I won't change my answer now.

Comment: Ok I guess that makes sense ill give that a go

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by the number of children being stored in each point in the 2D array?

Comment: Your original attempt asks for number of houses and number of children.  If the second dimension of the array is already the (fixed) number of children, does it then make sense to ask the user for the number of children?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: `printf(... , i+1, j+1)` still makes no sense.

Comment: @alk Yes it does.  Numbers (and people) are generally tallied using counting numbers, which start at one, not zero.  Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: The related format string provides just *one* conversion specifier, not *two*.