# Writing to an array of arrays and displaying the seperate entities in the array of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a code which basically has 10 streets, and in each street the user is asked for the number of houses and the number of kids in each house. But when I try to display the number of streets work, the number of houses work, but the number kids in the houses does not. I would also like to know how to add the number of kids in the street, like a street 1 has 10 kids in total (I don't really know how to do this part). I think the problem is in my for loops, but I am not entirely sure what the problem is. The code is shown below:

```
int main()
{

int i=0;
int j=0;
int streets[10];
int houses=0;
int KidsInStreets[houses];
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("How many houses are there in street %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d",&houses);
    for (j=0;j<houses;j++)
    {
        printf("How many kids are there in house number %d, in street number %d:\n", j+1, i+1);
        scanf("%d", &KidsInStreets[j]);
    }
}
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<houses;j++)
    {
        printf("Street:%d House:%d Kids:%d\n", i+1, j+1, KidsInStreets[j]);//Kids in street output and houses output have bugs, such as all the houses in the street need to be displayed, and the kids thing is just not working
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The line `int KidsInStreets[houses].` is the problem. `houses` is zero, so you create an array with size 0.

Comment: Oh ok, so the array of KidsInStreets[houses] should be made after the first for loops?

Comment: You could either declare it as an array with a size of a known maximum, or - like you proposed - declare it after you know the number of houses. Google for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Eerily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049598/asking-for-user-input-for-a-2d-array-and-storing-the-data-in-the-array-in-c

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `houses` is zero when you do `int KidsInStreets[houses];`. But the real problem is that you just have **one** array but you need an array for **each** street.

Try something like:

```
int* streets[10];   // Notice *
int houses=0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("How many houses are there in street %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d",&houses);
    streets[i] = malloc(houses * sizeof(int)); // Allocate array
    for (j=0;j<houses;j++)
    {
        printf("How many kids are there in house number %d, in street number %d:\n", j+1, i+1);
        scanf("%d", &streets[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The problem is however that now you don't know how many houses there were in each street. So you need to save that information. To do that you could make a struct or an extra array.

An extra array is not so elegant but very easy:

```
int* streets[10];   // Notice *
int houses_in_street[10];
int houses=0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("How many houses are there in street %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d",&houses);
    streets[i] = malloc(houses * sizeof(int)); // Allocate array
    houses_in_street[i] = houses;
    for (j=0;j<houses;j++)
    {
        printf("How many kids are there in house number %d, in street number %d:\n", j+1, i+1);
        scanf("%d", &streets[i][j]);
    }
}


for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<houses_in_street[i];j++)
    {
        printf("Street:%d House:%d Kids:%d\n", i+1, j+1, streets[i][j]);
    }
}
```

A better solution would be a struct like:

```
struct street {
    int number;
    int houses;
    int* kids_in_house;
};

// use it like
struct street streets[10];
```

Comment: Ok, the code works perfectly, what would i need to do in order to have something like: "total kids in street %d is :..."? How would I modify the code?

Comment: This the code I added to modify it to do a sum of teh elemnts in teh array, but it does a cumalitive sum:

Comment: for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<houses_in_street[i];j++)
    {
        printf("Street:%d\n House:%d Kids:%d\n", i+1, j+1, streets[i][j]);
        sum=sum+streets[i][j];
    }
    printf("Total number of kids in street %d are %d\n", i+1, sum);
}
}

Comment: @Jiren - the code in your comment seems fine - just remember to initialize `sum` to zero

Comment: rather than it doing a cumilative sum, how can I change it to do a sum of each street?

Comment: @jiren Let me suggest that you take the code now and post it as a new answer. It's hard to view/write code in comments :-)

Comment: Ok, will do, sorry for rhe incovenience

Answer (score 0):

```
void streets()
{
int i=0;
int j=0;
int* streets[10];
int houses_in_street[10];
int houses=0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("How many houses are there in street %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d",&houses);
    streets[i] = malloc(houses * sizeof(int)); // Allocate array
    houses_in_street[i] = houses;
    for (j=0;j<houses;j++)
    {
        printf("How many kids are there in house number %d, in street number 
%d:\n", j+1, i+1);
        scanf("%d", &streets[i][j]);
    } 
}


for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<houses_in_street[i];j++)
    {
        printf("Total number of presents required for street:%d house:%d\n= 
%d\n", i+1, j+1, streets[i][j]);

 total_number_of_presents_required=
total_number_of_presents_required+streets[i][j];
    }
}
printf("Total number of presents required in the streets 
is:%d\n",total_number_of_presents_required);

}
```